# Given an array of integers, how can I find all common multiples up to a maximum number?

Tags: c#, arrays

This is my first question on this site. I am practicing on a problem on Hackerrank that asks to find numbers "Between two Sets". Given two arrays of integers, I must find the number(s) that fit the following two criteria:
1) The elements in the first array must all be factors of the number(s)
2) The number(s) must factor into all elements of the second array

I know that I need to find all common multiples of every element in the first array, but those multiples need to be less than or equal to the minimum value of the second array. I first sort the first array then find all the multiples of ONLY the largest number in the first array (again, up to a max of the second array's minimum) and store those multiples in a list. Then, I move on to the second largest element in the first array and test it against the array of existing multiples. All elements in the list of existing multiples that isn't also a multiple of the second largest element of the first array is removed. I then test the third largest value of the first array, all the way to the minimum value. The list of existing multiples should be getting trimmed as I iterate through the first array in descending order. I've written a solution which passes only 5 out of the 9 test cases on the site, see code below. My task was to edit the getTotalX function and I created the getCommonMultiples function myself as a helper. I did not create nor edit the main function. I am not sure why I am not passing the other 4 test cases as I can't see what any of the test cases are.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Solution {

    /*
     * Complete the getTotalX function below.
     */
    static int getTotalX(int[] a, int[] b) {
        //get minimum value of second array
        int b_min = b.Min();

        //create List to hold multiples
        List<int> multiples = getCommonMultiples(a, b_min);

        //create List to hold number of ints which are in solution
        List<int> solutions = new List<int>();
        foreach(int x in multiples)
        {
            foreach(int y in b)
            {
                if (y % x == 0 && !solutions.Contains(x))
                {
                    solutions.Add(x);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return solutions.Count;
    }

    static List<int> getCommonMultiples(int[] array, int max)
    {
        //make sure array is sorted
        Array.Sort(array);
        int x = array.Length - 1; //x will be the last # in array -- the max
        int y = 1;
        //find all multiples of largest number first and store in a list
        int z = array[x] * y;
        List<int> commonMultiples = new List<int>();
        while(z <= max)
        {
            commonMultiples.Add(z);
            y++;
            z = array[x] * y;
        } 

        //all multiples of largest number are now added to the list
        //go through the smaller numbers in query array
        //only keep elements in list if they are also multiples of smaller 
        //numbers

        int xx = array.Length - 2;
        for(int a = array[xx]; xx >= 0; xx--)
        {
            foreach(int b in commonMultiples.ToList())
            {
                if (b % a != 0)
                {
                    commonMultiples.Remove(b);
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        return commonMultiples;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH"), true);

        string[] nm = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

        int n = Convert.ToInt32(nm[0]);

        int m = Convert.ToInt32(nm[1]);

        int[] a = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), aTemp => Convert.ToInt32(aTemp))
        ;

        int[] b = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), bTemp => Convert.ToInt32(bTemp))
        ;
        int total = getTotalX(a, b);

        tw.WriteLine(total);

        tw.Flush();
        tw.Close();
    }
}
```

Again, I can't see the test cases so I do not know what exactly the issue is. I went through the code line by line and can't find any OutOfBoundExceptions or things of that sort so it has to be a logic issue. Thanks for the help!

A typical sample involves 3 lines of input. The first line has 2 integers which gives the length of the first array and the second array, respectively. The second line will give the integers in the first array. The third line will give the integers in the second array. The output needs to be the total number of integers "in between" the two arrays. It will looks like this:

Sample Input

```
2 3
2 4
16 32 96
```

Sample Output

3

Explanation: 2 and 4 divide evenly into 4, 8, 12 and 16.
4, 8 and 16 divide evenly into 16, 32, 96.
4, 8 and 16 are the only three numbers for which each element of the first array is a factor and each is a factor of all elements of the second array.

Comment: How large are those input numbers? Can you give a typical sample (edit into your question)

Comment: In a for-loop, the first part is executed once: in ‘for (int a =array[xx];...‘ that a keeps its value

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Isn't it updated each time xx is decremented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues with the code you posted.

**Firstly**, as [@Hans Keﬆing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56465707/given-an-array-of-integers-how-can-i-find-all-common-multiples-up-to-a-maximum#comment99523032_56465707) pointed out, `a = array[xx]` is not being updated each time in the for loop. Since the variable `a` is only used in one spot, I recommend just replacing that use with `array[xx]` and be done with it as follows:

```
    for(int xx = array.Length - 2; xx >= 0; xx--)
    {
        foreach(int b in commonMultiples.ToList())
        {
            if (b % array[xx] != 0)
            {
                commonMultiples.Remove(b);
```

For your understanding of `for` loops: to properly increment `a` each time you'd write the `for` loop like this:

```
for(int xx = array.Length - 2, a = array[xx]; xx >= 0; xx--, a = array[xx])
```

The first part of the `for` loop (up until **;**) is the initialization stage which is only called before the entering the loop the first time. The second part is the while condition that is checked before each time through loop (including the first) and if at any time it evaluates to false, the loop is broken (stopped). The third part is the increment stage that is called only after each successful loop.

Because of that in order to keep `a` up to date in the `for` loop head, it must appear twice.

**Secondly**, your `solutions` in `getTotalX` is additive, meaning that each multiple that works for each value in array `b` is added as a solution even if it doesn't fit the other values in `b`. To get it to work the way that you want, we have to use a `Remove` loop, rather than an `Add` loop.

```
    List<int> multiples = getCommonMultiples(a, b_min);

    //create List to hold number of ints which are in solution
    List<int> solutions = multiples.ToList();
    foreach(int x in multiples)
    {
        foreach(int y in b)
        {
            if (y % x != 0)
            {
                solutions.Remove(x);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

You could also use LINQ to perform an additive solution where it takes into account `All` members of `b`:

```
    //create List to hold number of ints which are in solution
    List<int> solutions = multiples.Where((x) => b.All((y) => y % x == 0)).ToList();
```

Comment: This works! Thank you for the idea of subtracting the solutions from the existing list, and to @Hans Keﬆing for pointing out my mistake with the array initialization.